# Firebase Storage sample with 400 error

Tags: firebase

It seems the Storage sample [https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js] sample has 400 error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (OK)

It seems the api key is wrong, but I actually copy it from firebase console.

My alive demo is here: https://fir-storage-25695.firebaseapp.com/

Thanks,

Comment: Hey @DotKu, let me know if my answer was not clear or you still have any other concern. thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you go a little deeper into your logs you will see that you are getting error `auth/operation-not-allowed` and it says `"The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section."`.

So, observing your code, on loading you are calling `signInAnonymously()`
and **whats happening is that you haven't enabled the anonymous authentication on your firebase console**. Make sure you go there and activate it.

[image]

Comment: Yeah. I'm wondering that, too. Would love to have a look at logs :D

Comment: even after this I still get an error `Multipart body does not contain 2 or 3 parts. `